# Python - %d format , not list

Tags: python

I am trying to print a data value from a list to a file. 
The error keeps printing out that

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not list
```

I don't seem to understand.. when I am trying to print each of them individually on the screen I don't have any problem.  Can you see where the problem could be?

```
   print >>map_file0, "%d,%d,%d" % (coreid[0],ret_perf[0][0],llc_perf[0][0])
```

Thanks

Comment: What are the values of `coreid[0]`, `ret_perf[0][0]`, and `llc_perf[0][0]`?

Comment: One or more of your arguments are not a type int. can you show what your variables equal?

Comment: @mish print the lists, `print coreid`, etc. and post that value.

Comment: Outch. My error, just after I posted it here.. I see that, I have not given the list attributes  correctly. the list did not have the value to print and was either printing NaN or 0 and 0 was correct.

Comment: Usually you can use `%s` for formatting ints. In this case it would have made it obvious which item was the list. Save `%d` for when you really need it for special formatting

Comment: It may be preference, but I would use the standard write method of the file object to output a string.  s = "string here", map_file0.write(s)

Comment: @monkut, What you suggest is the preferred way. `>>` won't even work anymore with Python3 since `print` is a function

Comment: @gnibbler nice to see that got cleaned up, I always thought that print redirect made python look more like perl.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the [newer string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting), there is no need to specify the type.

```
# old
old_method = "%d,%d,%d" % (1, 2, 3)

# new (2.7)
new_method = "{},{},{}".format(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the python documentation, [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations), the `%d` is ***Signed integer decimal***. Means that one or more values you are trying to format are lists and not integers. You might have a list of list.